# How can I add line breaks for my output? (im super beginner)

Tags: python-3.x, output

I have printed out a list of numbers, but I want to make the output 'cleaner'

```
a,b=3,4

while (b<=1000000):
    if b>= 100 and b<=1000000:
        print(b, end = ' ')
    a,b = b,a+b
```

output:

```
123 199 322 521 843 1364 2207 3571 5778 9349 15127 24476 39603 64079 103682 167761 271443 439204 710647
```

What I want to do with it is, add a line break after every 5 numbers, so:

```
123 199 322 521 843
1364 2207 3571 5778 9349
...
```

and so forth.

I've done some googling and searching and I stumbled upon this (an example):

```
i = 1
while i < 30:
    print(i, end = '\n' if i % 5 == 0 else " ")
    i += 1
```

but when i try to add it to my code:

```
while (b<=1000000):
    if b>= 100 and b<=1000000:
        print(b, end = '\n' if b % 5 == 0 else " ")
    a,b = b,a+b
```

the output is still the same, all in one line:

```
123 199 322 521... 167761 271443 439204 710647
```

any ideas?

Comment: Keep count of how many values you have printed; that will tell you when to do a line break.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a counter and then print a newline after every 5 numbers:

```py
a,b = 3,4
cnt = 1

while (b <= 1000000):
    if b >= 100 and b <= 1000000:
        print(b, end='')
        if cnt > 1 and cnt % 5 == 0:
            print('\n', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
        cnt += 1
    a,b = b,a+b
```

This prints:

```
123 199 322 521 843
1364 2207 3571 5778 9349
15127 24476 39603 64079 103682
167761 271443 439204 710647
```

Comment: Don't need `cnt>1`; could use conditional expression (as in original code) instead of `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, im still new to coding, so this is more helpful than you realise.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you found, `i` is both what is being printed & a count of what has been printed; you conflated the two.

```
i = 1
while (b<=1000000):
    if b>= 100 and b<=1000000:
        print(b, end = '\n' if i % 5 == 0 else " ")
        i += 1
    a,b = b,a+b
```